# How to say to aws "Here is my docker-compose file, create instances based on that just like docker-compose build does"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I've been searching for an answer to this question for quite some time now. I've read almost every official aws written tutorial on their services and watched several youtube videos, read some third party tutorials on the subject but there doesn't seem to be a simple easy-to-follow solution to this. Then I tried to search on stackoverflow and although there are 2-3 similiar questions they are either not an exact problem or their solutions are not applicable/understandable and require further explanations.

**Problem:**

On my PC I do `docker-compose build` and then `docker-compose up` and voila, I have my instances up and running without problems.

I want to do the exact same thing but so that every service in docker-compose.yml file starts on its own EC2 Instance (or whichever service that AWS offers). Then I want to be able to change my code and push it to github/gitlab/bitbucket (in my case gitlab) and for it to be deployed to my instances.(but this goes into topic about CI/CD so not important for this exact question)

I think that most of people who are used to docker and docker compose and want to start using AWS will or already have encountered this problem.

A step by step solution( or at least a link or pointing me in the right direction) would be really useful because at the moment there is just too much information on EC2, ECR, ECS, IAM and bunch of other stuff and for a beginner in the AWS world it is really really hard to understand and follow.

EDIT:

I know that it probably isn't that simple but a solution must exists even if it is something as cumbersome as creating every single service by itself on ECS (as mentioned in comments). If it is the only way then sure, I all for it, and I did try several of those tutorials but still didn't succeed in my goal.

Comment: AWS does not offer a docker compose service. The closest you can get to what you are describing would be to spin up each docker image separately using ECS+Fargate.

Comment: since "docker-compose build" is a perfect answer for your title, you should change the title to better reflect what you are actually asking

Comment: @MarkB I did read a lot on those two but that seems like a lot of complicated work for basically copying a simple docker-compose functionality. However, given the right directions and tutorials it is something I am willing to try/use in order to solve this problem. But again, those tutorials are also problematic to follow since I tried several of them.

Comment: @wotanii I did updated the title but I want it to stay in this form because of others that might have the same problem

Comment: The easiest answers to this probably boil down to getting an EC2 instance, installing Docker on it, and proceeding as normal.  Have you tried that, and are there specific problems you're running into?

Comment: @ii7scw I understand, but the fact remains that AWS is complicated and the level of simplicity you are looking for does not exist. You might look at this Azure service https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-multi-container On AWS the simplest way to stand up a docker container is probably Elastic Beanstalk https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker.html which you could use to spin up each of your services individually.

Comment: @DavidMaze the question mentions using the docker compose file to spin up one EC2 server per image. That's not something you can do by just running `docker-compose up` on an EC2 instance.

Comment: @DavidMaze While that is a possible solution it is not what I am trying to do. In that case I would need 1 big EC2 instance and inside that I would have all my services...since this app is microservice architecture I really need multiple ec2 instances

Comment: @MarkB thanks for the advice on beanstalk, I'll look into it asap